# Reading multiple wildcard paths into a DataFlow PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In my situation, I have a bunch of events that are stored in small files in Storage under a Date folder. My data might look like this:

```
2022-01-01/file1.json
2022-01-01/file2.json
2022-01-01/file3.json
2022-01-01/file4.json
2022-01-01/file5.json

2022-01-02/file6.json
2022-01-02/file7.json
2022-01-02/file8.json

2022-01-03/file9.json
2022-01-03/file10.json
```

The DataFlow job will take start and end date as input, and needs to read all files within that date range.

I am working off of this guide: https://pavankumarkattamuri.medium.com/input-source-reading-patterns-in-google-cloud-dataflow-4c1aeade6831

I see there is a way to load a list of files into a PCollection:

```py
def run(argv=None):
    # argument parser
    # pipeline options, google_cloud_options
    
    file_list = ['gs://bucket_1/folder_1/file.csv', 'gs://bucket_2/data.csv']
    
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    
    p1 = p | "create PCol from list" >> beam.Create(file_list) \
        | "read files" >> ReadAllFromText() \
        | "transform" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x) \
        | "write to GCS" >> WriteToText('gs://bucket_3/output')

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

I also see there is a way to specify wildcards, but I haven't seen them used together.

Wondering if beam.Create() supports wildcards in the file list? This is my solution:

```py
def run(argv=None):
    # argument parser
    # pipeline options, google_cloud_options
    
    file_list = ['gs://bucket_1/2022-01-02/*.json', 'gs://2022-01-03/*.json']
    
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    
    p1 = p | "create PCol from list" >> beam.Create(file_list) \
        | "read files" >> ReadAllFromText() \
        | "transform" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x) \
        | "write to GCS" >> WriteToText('gs://bucket_3/output')

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

Have not tried this yet as I'm not sure if it's the best approach and don't see any examples online of anything similar. Wondering if I'm going in the right direction?

EDIT: This is my revised code after reading the answers:

```
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        file_list = ['gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/2022-01-02/*.json', 'gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/2022-01-03/*.json']

        for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
            p = (p | f"Read Text {i}" >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(file, skip_header_lines = 0))
        
        p = (p | "write to GCS" >> WriteToText('gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/output'))
```

EDIT2: Using the original code:

```
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        file_list = ['gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/2022-01-02/*.json', 'gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/2022-01-03/*.json']

        for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
            p = (p | 
            f"Read Text {i}" >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(file, skip_header_lines = 0)
            | f"write to GCS {i}" >> WriteToText('gs://ext-pub-testjeff.appspot.com/output'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach if it's not possible to use a single url with a wildcard :

```py
def run():
    # argument parser
    # pipeline options, google_cloud_options
 
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        file_list = ['gs://bucket_1/2022-01-02/*.json', 'gs://2022-01-03/*.json']

        for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
            (p
               | f"Read Text {i}" >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(file, skip_header_lines = 0)
               | f"transform {i}" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x)
               | f"write to GCS {i}" >> WriteToText('gs://bucket_3/output'))
```

We do a foreach on the file paths with wildcard.
For each element we apply a pipeline with read and write.

Comment: If we do this, how do we merge the PCollections? Is there a way to create a dynamic list of PCollections and merge them together?

Comment: The merge will be automatic in this case, the same pipeline will be applied for each path including the wildcard.

Comment: Since we are assigning the transformed pipeline to p1, Doesn't that mean the transformations get reset at every iteration?

Comment: I removed the variable p1 that is useless.
Don't hesitate to try this code please.

The code will execute the pipeline for each file path.

Comment: I did try this code myself, but for some reason it only writes one of the files back to Cloud Storage.

Comment: BTW updated the original answer to show my changes to the code.

Comment: Your code is different from the code I proposed. In my code, all the pipeline is applied in the for loop. Can you try in this way please ?

Comment: Hey I am OP but having some trouble with corp access, I followed your instructions and here is a pastebin with my sample code:
https://pastebin.com/gZngmCVY

I had to modify it a bit so that each step in the pipeline has a unique label. Otherwise I get: `A transform with label "write to GCS" already exists in the pipeline. To apply a transform with a specified label write pvalue | "label" >> transform.`

It still runs into the issue that only 1 of the files gets written to the output. I see "output-00000-of-00001" containing the result of 1 file, even though there are two files.